Undocumented bytes in .theme file format
According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/themesfileformat-overview#metrics-section), the Metrics section of a .theme file looks like
IconMetrics=76 0 0 0 139 0 0 0 139 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 245
255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 144 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0 119 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 216
31 7 0 28 52 1 1 216 31 7 0 176 36 1 1 
NonclientMetrics=84 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 18
0 0 0 18 0 0 0 245 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
188 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 0 0 0
15 0 0 0 245 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 188 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0 0 80 37 11
0 0 0 0 0 140 221 6 0 227 115 247 119 2 40 11 0 7 0 0
0 18 0 0 0 18 0 0 0 245 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 144 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0
0 0 0 0 0 60 222 6 0 50 71 252 119 120 1 7 0 76 73 252
119 8 6 7 0 245 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
144 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0 119 0
0 7 0 120 1 7 0 120 1 7 0 40 37 11 0 120 1 7 0 120 1 7
0 245 255 255 255 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 144 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 84 97 104 111 109 97 0 0 92 1 0 0 136 4
0 0 40 37 1 1 0 0 7 0 184 221 6 0 46 75 232 119 

, and those bytes correspond to ICONMETRIC and NONCLIENTMETRICS structures. But the ICONMETRIC structure size is smaller than the number of bytes in the IconMetrics part of the Metrics section, so when you conform the IconMetrics part bytes to an ICONMETRIC structure, you get:
cbSize           =  76   0   0   0 
iHorzSpacing     = 139   0   0   0 
iVertSpacing     = 139   0   0   0 
iTitleWrap       =   1   0   0   0 
lfHeight         = 245 255 255 255 
lfWidth          =   0   0   0   0 
lfEscapement     =   0   0   0   0 
lfOrientation    =   0   0   0   0 
lfWeight         = 144   1   0   0 
lfItalic         =   0 
lfUnderline      =   0 
lfStrikeOut      =   0 
lfCharSet        =   0 
lfOutPrecision   =   0 
lfClipPrecision  =   0 
lfQuality        =   0 
lfPitchAndFamily =   0 
lfFaceName       =  84  97 104 111  109  97   0 (Tahoma)
119
  0   0   7   0
  0   0   0   0 
216  31   7   0 
 28  52   1   1 
216  31   7   0 
176  36   1   1 


The question is, what are the remaining bytes--
119
  0   0   7   0
  0   0   0   0 
216  31   7   0 
 28  52   1   1 
216  31   7   0 
176  36   1   1 


? Same problem with NonclientMetrics part.

lfFaceName buffer is 32 characters in size, so it's just uninitialized data following the null terminated font name.
